# .Net Multi threaded application slow on a powerful server vis a vis regular server

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance

I have following two server configurations:

Server1:

> Processor  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4617 0 @ 2.90GHz, 2900 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 6 Logical Processor(s)
>       Processor   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4617 0 @ 2.90GHz, 2900 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 6 Logical Processor(s)
>       Processor   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4617 0 @ 2.90GHz, 2900 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 6 Logical Processor(s)
>       Processor   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4617 0 @ 2.90GHz, 2900 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 6 Logical Processor(s)
>
> OS Name        Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard
>
> Physical Memory        128 GB

Server2:

> Processor  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650  @ 2.67GHz, 2659 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
>
> OS Name        Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
>
> Physical Memory        24 GB

My application use the Task API to parallelize the parent and child component, where parent class task / thread would invoke, child class object, which again parallelize a module using Task API.

Initially I have run on server2, and have got the performance results, which were better than running the application without Tasks, now my expectation as in theory was that when Server1 comes in the picture, there should be some performance enhancement, since the child component has at least 20 -30 tasks running in parallel, but to my utter surprise, it has worsened by 3-4 times, so if earlier single execution of child component was taking 2 seconds, now it is taking 7-8 seconds, which is a disaster for us, as the child component may get invoked few million times and I am not sure, how to go about resolving the issue, especially since the Server1 is suppose to be the production. Any pointers to get me started to resolve the issue would be great.

Please let me know if you need more details / clarification.

thanks,

Mrinal

Comment: Please utilize at least a .NET profiler to get underlying data on the runtime characteristics of your application. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools

Comment: Thanks Lex, I will figure out which performance profiler tools help us in understand the issue best, do you recommend any of the free tools, that is more intuitive than others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague especially since we have no code to work with or any idea of the framework. But I can think of some general things that might be causing your problem. First off just because you add more cores doesn't mean you will get better processing, in fact depending on how the code is written, you could get the exact opposite which is what you are seeing. My  primary suspicion would be that you have some common object(s) that all your task are using which your tasks end up fighting over resulting in bottlenecks. So my first question would be do you have any shared resources among tasks? Basically are the tasks that you are spawning individual units of work (i.e. have no dependencies shared between tasks)? Another warning sign that you have a bottleneck is your CPU usage. Theoretically if you have many individual units of work that are all independent of one another you should be consuming a lot of CPU since .Net will be able to run them all in parallel. If you have a lot of task, but low CPU usage more then likely some shared object is killing your parallelization.

Comment: As suggested since my question is vague so, marking this one as answer, since I looked closely in the code and indeed the unnecessary locks, which were there for an extra care to avoid synchronization issue, were bring down the application performance, when they were not modifying any shared Data structure. I could not post the code, since this is part of a big project and I couldn't have afford to spend time recoding a simpler version to reproduce the issue, I was just looking for the generic answers that can help me shoot in dark :).